# How to add Cordova plugins to Xcode project with embedded Cordova WebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an Xcode iOS project to which I have successfully added a Cordova WebView.

I stumbled through their tutorial. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/webview.html

**How can I add plugins to it?**

---

If I try to use Plugman suggest, I get this error:

`plugman install --platform ios --project path/to/my/custom/xcode/project --plugin cordoba-plugin-console`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':CordovaError: The provided path "path/to/my/custom/xcode/project" is not a Cordova iOS project.`

Of course this is true. The instructions I followed were for adding the web view to a NON Cordova project.

---

I also tried adding plugins to the Cordova iOS project before bringing over the config.xml and such from it to my own project.

The result is that the project will launch but I get these errors in the Xcode console:

`CDVPlugin class CDVFile (pluginName: file) does not exist.`

`ERROR: Plugin 'File' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.`

---

I tried bringing over the `Plugins` folder from the reference project to my project. (The one that has files like `CDVLogger.h/m` and `CDVFile.h/m`

When I do this, I get build errors:

> duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVCapture.o
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVLocalFilesystem.o duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVCapture.o
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
>   duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVCapture.o
>       /Users/dustinbahr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AudioCapture-hbvwvtednsahtmgofuophnczsnmj/Build/Intermediates/AudioCapture.build/Debug-iphoneos/AudioCapture.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVFile.o
>   ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Cordova plugins to your project by using cocoapods. Create a Podfile and specify in it the dependencies to get from the cocoapods registry, see an example here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/phonegap-ios-template.

As for the `duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix` you get, the solution  is on the declaration of the constant: `kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix`. On the file `CDVFile.h` find the declaration of `kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix` and declare it as `extern`:

```
extern NSString* const kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix;
```

Declaring something as `extern` tells the compiler the type AND that the variable will be defined somewhere else.